# Per-programmer #define in Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a Visual Studio 2013 C++ project with another programmer, using subversion to control the source. What we need is some way for each programmer to be able to write experimental code that will compile just for them, but not the other. So for me it might be:

```
 #ifdef MATTHEW
   CallMyTestFunction();
 #endif
```

and the MATTHEW definition would be only there on my computer, and not theirs, even when we have both checked in and updated the source at any time.

I see there is a vcxproj.user file, but this appears to be unrelated to this task. Given this must be a common requirement, and I'm a newbie too VS2013, I hope that this is an easy one to solve. Thanks.

Comment: This has a knack for getting out of hand badly, with neither programmer being able to generate a comparable build.  Poor substitute for unit tests.  You can reference an environment variable in you preprocessor definitions, like %USERNAME%

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it's a concern, but I need to be able to add code that is pre-release while the other programmer concentrates on line-of-business stuff. Without being able to isolate my code, I can't check in. I can't see how unit tests would make a difference to that aspect of programming life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - it's easy:

1. Open project properties
2. Go to: `C/C++` --> `Preprocessor`
3. At the end of `Preprocessor Definitions` field add: `;USER_$(USERNAME)` or `;USER_$(COMPUTERNAME)` - depends on how you want to distinguish users: by username or computer name.

Then in the code:

```
#ifdef USER_matthew
   CallMyTestFunction();
#endif
```